# PHP replace string where nothing follows it

Tags: php, regex

I need to do a find/replace using a regex.

I have the following scenarios:

```
URL 1: /test-category1/test-category-2/
URL 2: /test-category1/test-category-2/test-category3/
```

How can I replace the first URL with something, only if nothing follows the last /? I.e only do the replace on URL1 and not URL2?

Comment: What does "*if nothing follows the last /*" mean? Can you give us an example of expected output?

Comment: In URL 2, nothing follows the last `/` as well, so why shouldn't it match, exactly?

Comment: Both URLs have nothing after the "last `/`".  Do you want to only replace URLs with 2 segments?

Comment: Yes, I want to find: /test-category1/test-category-2/ exactly and replace with /test-category2/, but only where nothing follows it.

Comment: So why not simply test for equality then? Why a regex if the string is fixed? In my opinion, you're not explaining your problem very well.

Answer (score 4):

This got -1'ed:

```
if ($url[(strlen($url) - 1)] == '/') {
    $url = $replacement;
}
```

Another try:

```
if (strlen(str_replace('/test-category1/test-category-2/', '', $url) == 0)) {
    $url = $replacement;
}
```

Update:

I claim to have the best and fastest solution:

```
if ($url == '/test-category1/test-category-2/') {
    $url = $replacement;
}
```

Comment: I'm out, this question is just too hard for me

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, you're asking for a **regex** replacement on an exact URL: `/test-category1/test-category-2/` and nothing else. Given those requirements, this is what you want:

```
preg_replace('#^/test-category1/test-category-2/$#', $replacement, $url);
```

This will replace the exact string only if it contains nothing after it.  The `$` matches an end-of-line.

Comment: It's still missing delimiters.

Comment: There're no needs to escape `-`

Comment: it wasnt me. I -1'ed the question only. but gave you +1 ^.^

Comment: @M42 - I agree, but nevertheless, that was the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_replace('~^/[^/]+/[^/]+/$~', '/repl/ace/')
```

But if you really want to replace exactly `/test-category1/test-category-2/` by `/test-category-2/` no regex needed here:

```
if ($url == '/test-category1/test-category-2/')
    $url = '/test-category-2/';
```

Comment: This simply doesn't answer the OP's question. It matches any URL with 2 segments (3 slashes). He has an exact URL he wants to match (clarified again in the comments). Sorry, but -1.

Comment: @StevenMoseley: So what? Doesn't this regex match his scenario?

Comment: Read the comments, he doesn't want just any match... he wants an **exact** match

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the middle of a larger string, you can use [negative lookbehind `(?<!)` and negative lookahead `(?!)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
<?php
$string = 'URL 1: /test-category1/test-category-2/
URL 2: /test-category1/test-category-2/test-category3/';


function swapURL($old,$replacement,$string){
    $pattern = '~(?<![A-Za-z0-9])'.$old.'(?![A-Za-z0-9])~';
    $string = preg_replace ($pattern,$replacement,$string);
    return $string;
}

$string = swapURL('/test-category1/test-category-2/','/test-category2/',$string);

echo $string;

?>
```

Output

```
URL 1: /test-category2/
URL 2: /test-category1/test-category-2/test-category3/
```

If you're doing this for a fixed string with a URL only (no new lines or other contents) then you would catch the start and end of the line.

```
function swapURL($old,$replacement,$string){
    $pattern = '!^'.$old.'$!';
    $string = preg_replace ($pattern,$replacement,$string);
    return $string;
}

$string = swapURL('/test-category1/test-category-2/','/new-page/',$string);

echo $string;
```